# ANDROID: How do you handle a BroadcastIntent not available on older API levels?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-9.0-pie

Context: I am trying to use the new [ACTION_APP_BLOCK_STATE_CHANGED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#ACTION_APP_BLOCK_STATE_CHANGED) Broadcast`Intent` that is only available with API level 28. Usually, when I deal with API level specific code, I would do something like

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
   //call new API
}
```

But because `BroadcastReceiver`s are set in the **AndroidManifest.xml** file, I am not sure how to do something similar.

Also as per [this example](https://www.journaldev.com/10356/android-broadcastreceiver-example-tutorial), it seems that the Android OS will handle receiving the intent and calling the relevant `BroadcastReceiver`, as defined in the **AndroidManifest.xml**. But my concern is that it will try to call it for the application running on an older SDK (e.g. API level 26 Oreo), and thus would cause application crashes.

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public MyReceiver() {
    }

    @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Toast.makeText(context, "Action: " + intent.getAction(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

How do I handle API level specific Broadcast `Intent`?

Comment: At runtime, on any device other than API 28, this constant `ACTION_APP_BLOCK_STATE_CHANGED` won't exist, so the broadcast will never be received because it will never be sent - easy test, create 2 emulators, one API 27 another API 28 and test from shell sending the broadcast.